# What's needed to add knockout.js to HotTowel?

Tags: knockout.js, hottowel

I have a project in VS 2012 using MVC4 and the HotTowel template.

I tried replacing details.html and details.js with the Hello World sample at http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html.

So details.html is now:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

And details.js:

```
 // Here's my data model
 var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

But now I get nothing from the details page. The progress bar in the nav block just stays there.

I must be missing something basic. Is there something in HotTowel I must do to get it working?

Comment: not sure if there is a hottowel problem or a typo somewhere else, but the code you have here works perfectly on its on http://jsfiddle.net/veHMb/

Comment: Yes, it works fine in jsfiddle.  I am wondering if there is something I must do in HotTowel before I can add code.

Answer (score 0):

Use F12 to check whether include `knockout.js` or not. if not, just include it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{SOME_URL}knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the HotTowel template includes it.  I can see <script src="/scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script> in the browser page source.

Comment: If you use google chrome, please Ctrl+U to check you source code whether it has knockout.js? If it does have it. Use F12 to see the javascript error.